# Como fazer uma consulta no banco de dados com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço um select em uma tabela no banco de dados com javascript

Comment: Select em uma base da dados com Javascript puro, você dificilmente fará algum dia. Vc não confundiu com Java não?

Comment: só se você usar javascript no "lado servidor", com nodejs por exemplo

Comment: Na verdade não confundi com Java, sei a diferença, mas foi uma duvida que surgiu se seria possível.

Comment: Mas fico grato pelos esclarecimentos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas vamos lá, é uma dúvida perfeitamente válida para um iniciante.

Não é a linguagem que acessa o banco de dados, é alguma biblioteca ou framework feito para aquela linguagem. Algumas linguagens têm acesso a alguns tipos de banco de dados na própria biblioteca padrão, outras não.

No caso do Javascript, sempre vai ser necessário instalar uma biblioteca de terceiros para acessar qualquer banco de dados.

No Javascript existe um complicador adicional: o ambiente em que ele roda. Os dois ambientes mais comuns são browser e Node.js. Até onde sei toda biblioteca para acesso a banco é feita para o ambiente Node.js. Você vai instalar via NPM.

O ambiente browser é bem mais restrito, acho que nem oferece condições para uma biblioteca deste tipo. Por exemplo: para acessar um banco MySQL você precisa fazer uma conexão TCP/IP, mas no browser isto é proibido por questões de segurança.

Mas digamos que sua necessidade é que uma aplicação rodando no browser precise acessar o banco. Você terá de fazer isso de forma indireta, com o browser fazendo requisições REST, GraphQL ou de outro tipo para um servidor Web, e este fazendo a consulta a um banco de dados.

*Não é recomendado de forma nenhuma* passar direto consultas SQL do browser para o servidor usando este esquema de intermediação, pois aí qualquer invasor poderia enviar consultas SQL "ruins" do tipo DROP DATABASE.